# System.StackOverflowException occurred in WindowsBase.dll when Binding DataGrid to IRealmCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, realm, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that show pending transactions. When the user selects a transaction and processes it, the transaction should no longer show in the datagrid. I have been using an ObservableCollection to back the DataGrid, but since I am using Realm to store the data, I would like to use an IRealmCollection and bind it to the DataGrid, but when I do that I get an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
```

[image]

This is the first time I've tried using Realm notification so I may be doing it incorrectly. This is what my View Model looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<SageTransaction> PendingTransactions { get; set; }
public IRealmCollection<SageTransaction> PendingTransactions2 { get; }

public TransactionsViewModel()
{
    var realm = Services.LocalRealmDB.InitializeRealm();            

    // Old Way that works
    PendingTransactions = new ObservableCollection<SageTransaction>( realm.All<SageTransaction>().Where( d => d.Posted == false ).ToList() );

    // New way that fails
    PendingTransactions2 = realm.All<SageTransaction>().Where( d => d.Posted == false ).AsRealmCollection();
}
```

and then I bind it to the DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"                             
            x:Name="PendingTransactions"                              
            ItemsSource="{Binding PendingTransactions2}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding PendingDetails}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True" Margin="10,10,10,0" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The collection populates, but throws the error directly after the constructor finishes. The Realm [Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest#notifications) says the you can pass the IRealmCollection directly to the view so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

So my questions are, by using IRealmCollection will the grid update automatically when the transaction is processed?

Am I using IRrealmCollection incorrectly and is there an example somewhere I can take a look at?

Comment: almost certainly you are in a recursion loop. You simply need to look at the stack in the debugger when this fails. You should be able to see the loop. You should see the same set of stack frames repeated over and over

Comment: @pm The stacktrace shows as Null in visual studio.

Comment: i mean - look in the call stack window in vs